# How to understand this writing in php

Tags: php

[image]

I saw this code when I was learning php through the source code, but I didn't understand this way of writing. What is the official name of this writing in php

Comment: With respect to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you should add this small piece of code instead of giving us a screenshot.

Comment: I don't think there's an official name as such. It's just closing and opening the tags, so some literal static content can be added to the output. If the function is called, then that HTML will be displayed in the output.

Comment: The PHP manual has this described in a section called [Escaping from HTML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php), if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given code example does nothing else as printing the given HTML elements.

```
function disinfo() {
?><h1>i muss you</h1><?
}

disinfo(); // results into <h1>i miss you</h1>
```

The declaration interrupts PHP and falls back into pure HTML. PHP has always been able to be written as a quasi template engine with HTML elements in a file that is interpretable by PHP. You do not even have to echo the markup. Since PHP is interupted with an ending delimiter and starts again with a starting delimiter everything in between is simply interpreted as html.

In fact there is no official name for this kind of output.